How to transpos columns to rows + duplicate given cell + delete all cells of given value in Excel?
I have a large spreadsheet (679 rows x 243 columns) consisting of a series of product SKUs in the first column, and each subsequent column represents an accessory. Every SKU to which the given accessory is applicable has the accessory part number populated. Because not every accessory is applicable to every SKU, a significant number of cells are populated by a dash (signifying "N/A").

I need to reorder this data in two columns: the first column to contain the product SKU, and the second column to contain the applicable accessory part numbers (each on its own row). The first column will repeat the product SKU in as many rows as necessary until all applicable accessories for that SKU have been populated. Subsequent SKUs will be populated similarly on subsequent rows. No dashes are to appear in the final accessories column.

How can I accomplish this automatically? Multiple steps are fine, I'm just trying to avoid manually copying/pasting/deleting data by hand.
TRANSPOSE puts the accessory numbers (and dashes) in columns as desired, but the SKU is put once as a column header rather than repeated in a parallel column. If I could insert a new column to the left of each existing column and populate the existing column header in every row that has data, I could then use VSTACK to place all the data in two columns. Then I could delete the rows with dashes with a column filter.


Look into Power Query Unpivot. You could select the SKU column and Unpivot Other Columns.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

Haven't tested for larger data: =LET(a,A2:A3,b,B2:G3,z,LAMBDA(r,TOCOL(IFS(b<>"-",r),2)),HSTACK(z(a),z(b)))

@bugdrown, Unpivot worked perfectly! Thanks!

@RonRosenfeld, with all due respect, I think my question contains all the necessary details apart from the images. I included the images simply to aid the understanding of those who had trouble visualizing what I described.

@P.b That worked as well! And maybe even a bit cleaner than the Unpivot option, since it doesn't require reformatting the source data for a power query.

@foolishgrunt Yes, you did supply a lot of detail. And I'm sure there are some that are smart enough to provide an accurate answer without having any data at all. But others need to create sample data to work on. By only posting an image, you require those people to spend time creating sample data themselves. So you are limiting the pool of those who might help you. I will sometimes create sample data in that situation, but most of the time I won't bother. Oh, and you could use that data from your first image in Power Query as is.

I see, so your suggestion would have been to supply a sample dataset as an illustration, rather than an image of my actual dataset. I'll keep that in mind.

@foolishgrunt No, that's not quite correct. My suggestion is to supply a sample data set as text (preferably as a Markdown Table, not as an illustration. Also providing a image (or text) of your expected results (which you did). There's nothing wrong with also providing an image of your actual data set if it adds information.

@ Ron Rosenfeld I was unclear. I meant to provide a sample useable dataset, not purely as visual aid. Thanks again.

Two solutions, each courtesy of the comments section.
Solution #1 (courtesy of P.b):

(If necessary) Copy/paste data into new worksheet and delete whatever few rows and columns whose data are irrelevant to the final product
On new worksheet, enter the following formula:
=LET(a,A2:A3,b,B2:G3,z,LAMBDA(r,TOCOL(IFS(b<>"-",r),2)),HSTACK(z(a),z(b)))

...where A2:A3 = SKUs range and B2:G3 = accessories range

Copy all data and past as values
Data > Filter
5elect all instances of "-" in column 2 and delete

Solution #2 (courtesy of bugdrown):

Copy/paste data into new worksheet and (if necessary) delete whatever few rows and columns whose data are irrelevant to the final product
Data > Get & Transform Data > From Table/Range
Select data range from new worksheet
Right-click header for column 1 (containing the product SKUs) > Unpivot Other Columns
(If necessary) Delete new column containing the old column titles
Close & Load
Data > Filter
Select all instances of "-" in column 2 and delete

